# Symfony2 + Doctrine : select query with conditional statment

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I would like to do something like :

```
return $qb
        ->select("f, g")
        ->addSelect(" (CASE WHEN (f.type = 'p') THEN 'panel' ELSE 'glass' END) as 'typeLable' ")
        ->from("Win4uAdminBundle:Filling", "f")
        ->join("f.gammes", "g")
        ->andWhere("f.isActive = :active")
        ->andWhere("g.id = :gamme")
        ->setParameter("active", 1)
        ->setParameter("gamme", $gammeId)
```

But doesn't work. error is :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got 'typeLable'
```

The goal is select the type and translate it in the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a typo, `typeLable` should be without quotes:

```
->addSelect(" (CASE WHEN f.type = 'p' THEN 'panel' ELSE 'glass' END) as typeLable ")
```

Comment: Right, but now I get this error : Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given

Comment: what is the whole call stack? What is causing this error?

Comment: g is object, so:
`->andWhere("g = :gamme")` and `->setParameter("gamme", $gammeEntity)`

Comment: The latest issue wasn't part of this trac. Thanks everything is ok now.